# New non-overlapping finite cover

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I need help in the following problem

> Let $B_{i}$ be a finite family of open balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that there exists a finite family of disjoint open balls $B'_{k}$  such that  $\bigcup_{k}{B'_{k}} ⊃ \bigcup_{i}{B_{i}}$ and $\sum_{k} {r(B'_{k})} ≤ \sum_{i} r(B_{i})$ where $r$ is the radius.

For the disjoint balls $B_{i}$ will keep them, what about the overlapping ones? How I can find this new cover? and does the result remain valid if we have a countable family of open balls with finite sum of the radii instead?